# Receive an email with Actionmailer and read the plain body text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using IMAP to receive some emails from gmail and then parse them with the new Rails 3 ActionMailer receive method.

```
raw_email   = imap.uid_fetch(uid, ['RFC822']).first.attr['RFC822']
email = UserMailer.receive(raw_email)
```

email is now a Mail::Message Class and to:, :from and :subject works fine. However I can't figure out how to get the plain text from the body. Before Rails 3 I could use the [tmail_body_extractors](http://github.com/sant0sk1/tmail_body_extractors) plugin to get the plain body.

How would you do this with Rails 3?

Jakobinsky:
email.body.raw_source is a bit closer be still gives me a lot of garbage.

> "--001636310325efcc88049508323d\r\nContent-Type: text/plain;
>   charset=ISO-8859-1\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding:
>   quoted-printable\r\n\r\nThis is some body
>   content\r\n\r\n--=20\r\nVenlig Hilsen\r\nAsbj=F8rn
>   Morell\r\n\r\n--001636310325efcc88049508323d\r\nContent-Type:
>   text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding:
>   quoted-printable\r\n\r\naf mail
> -- 
> Venlig
>   Hilsen
> Asbj=F8rn
>   Morell
> \r\n\r\n--001636310325efcc88049508323d--"

Should I roll my own helpers for cleaning up the raw_source or is there already a method ,gem or helper for that?

Answer (score 5):

See the answer on this question:
[Rails - Mail, getting the body as Plain Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868205/rails-mail-getting-the-body-as-plain-text)

In short the solution is:

`plain_part = message.multipart? ? (message.text_part ? message.text_part.body.decoded : nil) : message.body.decoded`

But I recommend reading the full answer as it is very good and comprehensive.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the plain body from body.parts. There is still however some headers left in the body:

```
if body.multipart?
  body.parts.each do |p|
    if p.mime_type == "text/plain"
      body = p.body
    end
  end
end
body.to_s
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to retrieve the body as simple as `email.body.raw_source`. 
I haven't tested it myself, but you can take a look as the source code for [ActionMailer:: Message#body](https://github.com/mikel/mail/blob/master/lib/mail/message.rb#L1110-1118).

Comment: There is no gem to fetch/clean an email body as far as I know. However you should be able to use some regex in order to clean this output.

Comment: I down voted this answer because it doesn't give the correct answer and actually confuses. `email.body.raw_source` returns the body with the MIME type headers, which can be avoided without any special "cleaning" required.