# Rails encoding in ASCII-8BIT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encoding, utf-8, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.1

I know this have been asked several times, but to me is happening something strange:

I have an index view where rendering certain characters (letters with accent) causes Rails to raise the exception

```
incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8
```

so i checked my strings encoding and this is actually ASCII-8BIT everywhere, even though i set the proper encoding to UTF-8 in my application.rb

```
config.encoding = "utf-8"
```

and in my enviroment.rb

```
Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8
```

and in my database it appear:

```
character_set_database = utf-8
```

as suggestend in some guides.

Strings are inserted with a textarea field and are not concatenated to any other already inserted string.

The strange things are:

- this happens only in the index view, whereas this is not happening in the show (same resource)
- this happens only for this model (which is an email, with subject and body, but this shouldn't affect anything)
- In my development environment everything goes well setting `str.force_encoding('utf-8')`, whereas in my production environment this is not working. (dev i'm with Ruby 2.0.0, in production Ruby 2.1.0, both Rails4, and both MySql)
- setting the file view with `# encoding utf-8` also doesn't work
- trying `str.force_encoding('ascii-8bit').encode('utf-8')` says `Encoding::UndefinedConversionError  "\xC3" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8` which is an **à**, while using `body.force_encoding('ascii-8bit').encode('UTF-8', :invalid => :replace, :undef => :replace, :replace => '?')`, replaces all accented charaters with a ?,  while `str.force_encoding('iso-8859-1').encode('utf-8')` obviously generates the wrong character (a `?`).

So my questions are 2:
- why is rails setting the string encodint to ascii-8bit?
- how to solve this issue?

I've already checked these questions (the newest ones with rails4):

[Rails View Encoding Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20346335/rails-view-encoding-issues)

["\xC2" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16218838/xc2-to-utf-8-in-conversion-from-ascii-8bit-to-utf-8)

[How to convert a string to UTF8 in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17022394/convert-string-to-utf8-in-ruby)

[Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\xE4" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428666/encodingundefinedconversionerror-xe4-from-ascii-8bit-to-utf-8)

and other resources also, but nothing worked.

Comment: Are you entering the accented characters into the view using a text editor?

Comment: it's a textarea_field

Comment: Is the source code files all utf-8 or are your text editor saving the files in ascii-8bit perhaps.

Comment: these are not string generated by my text editor...anyway files are in UTF-8

Comment: I'm struggling with a similar issue (getting `incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8` errors from user entered data). Were you able to solve your problem? Did you find a way to replicate it in a test?

Comment: I was not able to definitely solve the problem, sorry. And it happens only from time to time without an apparent reason.

Comment: I found a workaround that I posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42078430/getting-incompatible-character-encodings-utf-8-and-ascii-8bit-error-when-disp?noredirect=1#comment71334714_42078430). It basically forces UTF-8 encoding on every read_attribute (if it's a string). Maybe it can help. Good luck

Comment: Well as written in my initial post, your workaround is basically as substituting str.force_encoding everywhere, and that works for me in dev environment, whereas it fails in production. No way :(

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a string literal in your source code somewhere that you then concatenate another string too. For instance:

```
some_string = "this is a string"
```

or even

```
some_string = "" #empty string
```

Those strings, stored in `some_string`, will be marked ASCII_8BIT, and if you then later do something like:

```
some_string = some_string + unicode_string
```

Then you'll get the error. That is, those strings will be marked ASCII-8BIT *unless* you add, to the top of the file where the string literals are created:

```
#encoding: utf-8
```

That declaration determines the default encoding that string literals in source code will have.

I am just guessing, because this pattern is a common source of this problem. To know more for sure, it would take more information than is in your question -- it would take debugging the actual source code, to figure out exactly what string is tagged as ASCII-8BIT when you expect it to be tagged UTF-8 instead, and exactly where that String came from.