# Message.body empty in ActionMailer Observer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, observers

I am using an Observer to log outgoing emails; it fires correctly but when I attempt to extract the body of the email I get an empty string.  The emails are definitely not blank and the logging record is definitely created. Breakpointing and inspecting `message.body` confirms that it is an empty string.

```
class MailObserver
  def self.delivered_email(message)
    for address in message.to
      user = User.find_by_email(address)
      if user
        UserMailerLogging.create!(user_id: user.id, email_type: message.subject, 
                                  contents: message.body, sent_at: Time.now)
      end
    end
  end
end

ActionMailer::Base.register_observer(MailObserver)
```

Answer (score 3):

In Rails 3, emails are built and sent using the [Mail](https://github.com/mikel/mail) gem. According to their docs

```
message.text_part # plaintext version
message.html_part # html version
```

You can also go a bit further depending on whether your emails are multipart or not.

```
message.text_part.body.decoded
```

This question here on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868205/rails-mail-getting-the-body-as-plain-text) may also be hefpful.