# ActionMailer- access Mail::Message content, or manually initialize view in controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, delayed-job

I've got a form where an internal user can request that informational materials be sent to a client.  When the form is submitted, it sends an email to the person in charge of physically mailing the materials to the client.

Now, I want to capture the content of the email so I can add a note to the client's show page, and I'm unsure how to go about it.

One option I've looked at is to use an `after_filter` in the `MaterialsRequestMailer`, but calling `message.body` returns a large string with way more text than I need and I want to avoid adding a bunch of parsing logic to get the message content.

Basically, I want what is generated by the `views/materials_request_mailer/send_request_notification.text.erb` template.  I've looked through http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mikel/mail/Mail/Message and can't find a method to return just the rendered template content.  Is there a way to do that?

If not, is there a way to manually initialize a `View` in the controller, where I already have the instance variables I'm passing to the mailer?  That doesn't seem to be an ideal solution, because I'm using `DelayedJob`, and the code for adding the note would be run before the email is actually sent. Also, due to `DelayedJob`, it appears that I can't directly access the mail object from within the controller (if I do `mail = MaterialsRequestMailer.delay.send_request_notification(...)` it assigns an instance of `Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job` to `mail`).

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution that works- `message.text_part.body.raw_source` is what I was looking for.  (credit to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15257098/2599738)

```
class MaterialsRequestMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  include AbstractController::Callbacks

  after_filter :add_note_to_client

  def send_request_notification(client, ...)
    @client = client
    ...
  end

  def add_note_to_client
    mail_text = message.text_part.body.raw_source
    @client.add_account_note(mail_text)
  end
end
```