# How to clean up a string (email body) with regards to special characters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, user-interface, imap

I have an email extracted from an IMAP account. I have encoded it like this:

```
body = imap.uid_fetch(uid, "BODY[TEXT]")[0].attr["BODY[TEXT]"].force_encoding('UTF-8')
```

So now it looks like this:

```
puts body.inspect => "\n--Apple-Mail-028364EC-0K8B-4FD7-87E8-97C28C324717\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\n\nHej=20\n\nI m=C3=A5 meget undskylde men jeg vil ikke k=C3=B8be produktet alligevel hvord=\nan g=C3=B8r vi det...=20\n\nHans Nielsen.         =20\nR=C3=B8rgade 65=20\n1234 G=C3=B8rlev\n\n"
```

I want to present the email in my Rails app, so the user of the app can review the email. But how do I clean up the body?

I want to remove this part:

```
--Apple-Mail-028364EC-0K8B-4FD7-87E8-97C28C324717
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

And clean up this part:

```
Hej=20

I m=C3=A5 meget undskylde men jeg vil ikke k=C3=B8be produktet alligevel hvord=
an g=C3=B8r vi det...=20

Hans Nielsen.         =20
R=C3=B8rgade 65=20
1234 G=C3=B8rlev
```

This means replacing the weird characters with the originally intended characters. Fyi, these are:

`=C3=A5` is `å`

`=C3=B8` is `ø`

`=20` is ???

`=` is ???

How to do this (without just using gsub)?

Comment: maybe you want to use `encode` instead of `force_encoding`? I don't think you can "clean up" this for any source encoding...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails - Mail, getting the body as Plain Text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868205/rails-mail-getting-the-body-as-plain-text)

Comment: Did you get the answer for your question? Since I tried solutions below but nothing help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a MIME parser, which should take care of removing the headers and getting rid of the quoted printable encoding.  Depending on the layout of your email, body[text] might get you a lot more than you want.  You need to either download the BODYSTRUCTURE and pick out the parts you want, or download the entire message (BODY[]) and use a MIME parser.

Comment: Hi Max. Which of the `BODY[TEXT]` should be replaced by `BODY[BODYSTRUCTURE]`/`BODY[]`. I've tried all combinations, but none of them returns anything. Also, could you refer me to a MIME parser that could be used in a Ruby on Rails app?

Comment: `imap.uid_fetch(uid, "BODY[TEXT]")[0].attr["BODY[TEXT]"]` change both to BODY[].  I can't help you with MIME parsers.  I know IMAP, not Ruby, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

The decoding result is:

```
Hej 

I må meget undskylde men jeg vil ikke købe produktet alligevel hvordan gør vi det... 

Hans Nielsen.          
Rørgade 65 
1234 Gørlev
```

It seems that `=` is `...` and `=20` is `"\n"`.

Comment: Thanks sawa. But how did you decode it? Because in the post that you refer to the `mail gem`is used. I am using the `net/imap`.